# Cannot find module 'jsonwebtoken' Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, jwt

i am trying to set up an user level authentication using node.js, so i go and do npm install -g jsonwebtoken --save. However, i run into problems when i use require('jsonwebtoken'); and try to compile my code, it gives me the error described above in the title. Now, for some reason, when i uninstall the JWT and try to run my code without it, it compiles, but obviously it doesn't work. I tried re-installing it, still no success. 
My npm --version
6.3.0

node --version
v11.1.0

npm install -g jsonwebtoken --save
+ jsonwebtoken@8.4.0

code:

```
'use strict';

require('jsonwebtoken');

exports.generateToken = async (data) => {
    return jwt.sign(data, global.SALT_KEY, { expiresIn: '1d' });
}

exports.decodeToken = async (token) => {
    var data = await jwt.verify(token, global.SALT_KEY);
    return data;
}

exports.authorize = function (req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    if (!token) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Acesso Restrito'
        });
    } else {
        jwt.verify(token, global.SALT_KEY, function (error, decoded) {
            if (error) {
                res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Token Inválido'
                });
            } else {
                next();
            }
        });
    }
};

exports.isAdmin = function (req, res, next) {
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    if (!token) {
        res.status(401).json({
            message: 'Token Inválido'
        });
    } else {
        jwt.verify(token, global.SALT_KEY, function (error, decoded) {
            if (error) {
                res.status(401).json({
                    message: 'Token Inválido'
                });
            } else {
                if (decoded.roles.includes('admin')) {
                    next();
                } else {
                    res.status(403).json({
                        message: 'Esta funcionalidade é restrita para administradores'
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: `const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');`

Comment: doesn't work unless i uninstall

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of installing it globally with the `-g` tag, just install it locally in your current working directory. Just do:

`npm install jsonwebtoken --save`

This is because you can not directly `require` a globally installed package in your code.

Answer (score 1):

### Just Do Simple:

```
npm install jsonwebtoken
```

Answer (score -3):

You are installing it system level node_modules folder. So it is not available in project level node_modules folder. Please remove  - g from npm install command

npm install  - - save jsonwebtoken

Comment: your answer doesn't contain anything new, everything was already written in the existing answer.